# How to convert Soap Response to Multidimensional Array?

Tags: android, soap

In my case, I have a soap response which has an "ArrayOfArrayOfString" type of values stored in it.

It is like an Array **A[4][4]**.

A[0][0] -> ServiceId

A[0][1] -> ServiceName

A[0][2] -> ServiceImageURL

A[0][3] -> ServiceDecription

A[0][4] -> ServiceIconURL

and its all same upto A[4][4].

How can I handle this type of response in android?

Code is something like:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transportSE.debug = true;

                                            Log.i("WebService", "msg:try_out");
    String[] columns = null;

    ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {
                                                    Log.i("WebService", "msg:try+in");
        transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                            
                                                    Log.i("WebService", "msg:SoapObject");


        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();           

                                                    Log.i("WebService", "Response");

try
            {
                // WhaT SHOULD I USE HERE to convert it to 2D Array//
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("CATCH BLOCK", e.getMessage());
            }
}
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("WebService", "msg:Exception error");
            Log.i("WebSerivce", e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Here is the Soap Code:::

Comment: Host: www.xyz.com
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length
    SOAPAction: "http://abc.net/webservices/LoadServices"
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <LoadServices xmlns="http://abc.net/webservices/" />
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: length

Comment: <soap:Body>
        <LoadServicesResponse xmlns="http://abc.net/webservices/">
          <LoadServicesResult>
            <ArrayOfString>
              <string>string</string>
              <string>string</string>
            </ArrayOfString>
            <ArrayOfString>
              <string>string</string>
              <string>string</string>
            </ArrayOfString>
          </LoadServicesResult>
        </LoadServicesResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>

Comment: i mean that is the "response" ur getting from webservice,is holding the data in xml format?

Comment: The response is in the form of Array.

I had printed the response on screen, it shows me::

anyType{string=123; string=ABC; string=URL; string=description; string=URL;}, anyType{same process keeps on for all services},...

Comment: ok i got it i am posting the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect working code to parse the complex data...

I am only doing this for A[0][1-4] and according to my soap response modify the code according to ur soap response.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)enevlop.getResponse();

            String str = result.getProperty(0).toString();
            // add a for loop for ur code and iterate it according to ur soap response and get all the node using getProperty(i);

            String str1 = lameParser(str);

            textView.setText(""+str1);
```

Now define lameParser() method:-

```
    public String lameParser(String input){

    String sName=input.substring(input.indexOf("sName=")+6, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("sName=")));

    int IGoals=Integer.valueOf(input.substring(input.indexOf("iGoals=")+7, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("iGoals="))));

    String sCountry=input.substring(input.indexOf("sCountry=")+9, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("sCountry=")));

    String sFlag=input.substring(input.indexOf("sFlag=")+6, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("sFlag=")));

    return sName+"\n"+Integer.toString(IGoals)+"\n"+sCountry+"\n"+sFlag;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, 
Thanks for your answer. But isn't there anyway by which I can store the RESULT directly to an 2-D array?

Comment: I was trying to use your code. I had an issue that before every value I have "string=", so its just picking A[0][0] everytime. Here is the snapshot of actual complete response.
https://885427425446120200-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/harryb87/scrnpng

Comment: Please check the snapshot. I am getting answer "string=922" whereas I just need "922". This answer is repeating for every field I specify as there is no different thing to specify rather then:: input.indexOf("string=") :(

Comment: here is correct code add 7:-input.indexOf("string=")+7(7 becoz 6 for string and 1 for = sign.6+1=7)

Comment: Hi, Yah it is good to do this way but its lengthy to use this stuff for A[25][16]. I have 25 services till now and each service has 16 properties stored in it. Is there any way to convert the response to 2-D Array by using something else?

Comment: I am getting the whole array in 0 location from soap so using loop to get according "getProperty(i)" is not possible. i.e. result.getProperty(0).toString(); =EQUALS= result.toString();

Comment: Thanks Himashu. This one worked for me to make it done in easy way. :)

Comment: can u help to answer this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903238/how-to-parse-soap-response-when-child-tags-have-different-name-and-no-of-tag-are

Answer (score 1):

Here's code to parse multiple child node of xml data...

```
public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output) throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException{

        Class theClass = output.getClass();
        Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Type type=fields[i].getType();
            fields[i].setAccessible(true);

            //detect String
            if (fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
                String tag = "s" + fields[i].getName() + "=";   //"s" is for String in the above soap response example + field name for example Name = "sName"
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].set(output, strValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            //detect int or Integer
            if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                String tag = "i" + fields[i].getName() + "=";  //"i" is for Integer or int in the above soap response example+ field name for example Goals = "iGoals"
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].setInt(output, Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }

            //detect float or Float
            if (type.equals(Float.TYPE) || type.equals(Float.class)) {
                String tag = "f" + fields[i].getName() + "=";
                if(input.contains(tag)){
                    String strValue = input.substring(input.indexOf(tag)+tag.length(), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if(strValue.length()!=0){
                        fields[i].setFloat(output, Float.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

If you will like the post give me the up vote so that visitors find it easily....

Comment: What I have done is all here, hope it'll help others to get it done in easy way.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
      Log.i("WebService", "Try Block");
      transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                          
      Log.i("WebService", "msg:SoapObject");

      SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
      Log.i("WebService", "Response on");
      int totalService = response.getPropertyCount();

      int i;
      String str ;
      String str1;

      for (i = 0; i < totalService; i++)
         {
        str = response.getProperty(i).toString();
            Log.i("WebService", "ForLoop "+ Integer.toString(i));
        str1 = lameParser(str, i);
            Log.i("WebService", "ForLoop: lameParser done");
            Log.i("WebService", "Value Stored:: "+ str1);
        }
        }                                               
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("WebService", "msg:Exception error");
            Log.i("WebSerivce", e.getMessage());

        }                   

    }



    private String lameParser(String input, int I)
    {
       int i = I;
       Log.i("WebService", "LameParse()" );
    try
    {
    String SId = input.substring(input.indexOf("{string=")+8, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("{string=")));
        String SName = input.substring(input.indexOf(" string=")+8, input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(" string=")));
        String SIurl = input.substring(input.indexOf("http"), input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf("http")));
        String SIcon = input.substring(input.indexOf("jpg; string=")+12, input.indexOf("; }", input.indexOf("jpg; string=")));

        // String[][] arr = new String[x][y]; is already initialized as local var of class.
        arr[i][0] = SId;
        arr[i][1] = SName;
        arr[i][2] = SIurl;
        arr[i][3] = SIcon;



        return SId + "\n" + SName + "\n" + SIurl +  "\n" +  SIcon + "\n" ;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("WebService", "catch exception" );
            Log.i("WebService", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I processed ArrayOfArrayOfString objects.

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
if (result.getPropertyCount() > 0) {
    SoapObject Rows = (SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);
    int nRows = Rows.getPropertyCount();
    for (int nRow=0; nRow<nRows; nRow++) {
        SoapObject Cols = (SoapObject)Rows.getProperty(nRow);
        int nCols = Cols.getPropertyCount();
        for (int nCol=0; nCol<nCols; nCol++) {
            String sCol = Cols.getProperty(nCol).toString();

            // Process sCol with nRow and nCol as array indexes
        }
    }
}
```